# Prove the uniform convergence of $\sum \frac{x^n(1-x)}{\log(n+1)}$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

As it's told on the title, need to prove the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{x^n(1-x)}{\log(n+1)}$ for $ x \in I=[0,1]$.

I tried to find the $\sup_{x \in I}g_n(x)$ (where $g_n(x)$ it's the function $\frac{x^n(1-x)}{\log(n+1)}$) to prove the uniform convergence with the Weierstrass-M test. 
The maximum value it's for $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$.
But then I get to prove $\sum\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}\log(n+1)}$ is conditionally convergent

Much thanks.

Comment: You may try to reassemble the partial sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n(1-x)}{\log(n+1)},$$ for instance adopting summation by parts technique, so that the Weierstrass $M$-test is applicable for the resulting sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We want to show

$$\tag 1 \sum_{n=M}^{N}\frac{x^n(1-x)}{\ln (n+1)}$$

is uniformly small if $M$ is large. Try summation by parts.

Comment: Okey, i'll try. Much thanks zhw!